# Avoiding SQL injection using mysql_real_escape_string and stripslashes

Tags: php, mysql

Is this a good way to prevent SQL injection before running a database query?

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($name));
$age = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($age));
$location = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($location));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need `stripslashes` and how about using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Comment: Short answer - no, it's not. Don't use `mysql_*` functions, but PDO, just like @Click suggested.

Comment: Your code breaks any string containing backslashes on recent/properly configured (magic quotes disabled) PHP installations. Never use `stripslashes` unconditionally. Only use it if `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` exists and returns `true`!

Comment: Show the database query that you are planning to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers it well:

- [mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html) by Ilia Alshanetsky

> So what can you do? The solution is to use **prepared statements**, which
>   are supported by nearly all PHP database extensions with the notable
>   exceptions of MySQL (ext/mysql) and SQLite2 (ext/sqlite). **So, to be on
>   the safe side, I'd recommend using the PDO interface to talks with
>   those databases or in the case of MySQL using the newer MySQLi
>   (ext/mysqli) extension. Those interfaces provide prepared statement
>   support, which allows for separation between query structure and the
>   query parameters.**

So to be on safer side, don't rely on `mysql_real_escape_string` alone, using prepared statements is much better.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It provides useful info about `mysql_real_escape_string` and when it fails. At least the downvoter could have commented what they think is wrong with the answer.

Comment: Well, the link you posted is deducing opinion by cornering mysql_* in a very specific case. Why somebody would need to even allow multibyte characters when their mysql char set is not supposed to support it? Though PDO seems handle this in its own way but how mysql_* is proved to be less secure?

Comment: @N.B. the security hole that Alshanetsky describes is a very esoteric one (ever worked with the GBK charset?) and can be fixed by setting the correct connection encoding. I agree that the `mysql_()` library is outdated and using PDO is superior, but it's perfectly possible to create safe queries with it, so "use PDO to be sure" is incorrect. Plus, "use PDO" has become a truly harmful meme - I recently had a long discussion with somebody who thought *any* query is automatically protected because he used PDO, leaving him with a huge injection hole.

Comment: @Pekka - there **exists** a hole with GBK charset. It doesn't matter whether I or anyone worked with it, it's worth mentioning that there **is** a hole so that developer in question can take it into account. Linked article describes it. Also, if a person thinks that all queries are safe if he/she uses PDO - it's their problem for *not reading* what PDO does. We're not all equally blessed with the gift of comprehension. Therefore, the ones who can't read often experience bobby tables type of attack.